# Jboss modules dependencies

Tags: spring, jboss

I have a question about dependencies in jboss modules. 
I have a spring application with structure like:

```
    myApp.war/
      --/WEB-INF
         --/classes/com/myapp/monitoring/IMonitoring.class  
         --/classes/com/myapp/monitoring/MonitoringFirst.class
         --/lib     
            my-core.jar
```

IMonitoring.class defines contract for monitoring class
        MonitoringFirst.class provides implementation for mornitoring, also it uses some class defined in my-core.jar for logging purpose so it depends on my-core.jar
in spring I define bean like:

```
        <bean id="myMonitoring" class="com.myapp.monitoring.MonitoringFirst">
```

then I decided to prepare another implementation of IMonitoring.class and provide it in sepatare jar as module in jboss modules so in jboss-deployment-structure.xml I have like:

```
        <jboss-deployment-structure>
            <deployment>
                <dependencies>
                    <module name="com.myapp.my-customization" />         
                </dependencies>
            </deployment>
        </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and my module defines jar with second implementation of IMonitoring.class inside

```
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.myapp.my-customization">
      <resources>
       <resource-root path="customization.jar"/> 
      </resources>

      <dependencies>
        <module name="my-core.jar"/>
      </dependencies>

    </module>
```

then in my spring I can use

```
    <bean id="myMonitoring" class="com.myapp.monitoring.MonitoringSecond">
```

but since MonitoringSecond also uses some class defined in my-core.jar for logging purpose I had to move my-core.jar to jboss modules - otherwise class needed in MonitoringSecond.class is not available and I have java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.LogManager from [Module "com.myapp.my-customization:main" from local module loader....

```
    Unfortunatelly class used for logging purpose (com.myapp.LogManager in my-core.jar) need information about name of the war in which it is called from, what can be achieved by asking for URL like 
    URL url = LogManager.class.getResource(LogManager.class.getSimpleName() + ".class");

    but this gives different results: 

    when class is located in myApp.war/WEB-INF/lib it gives:
    vfs:/C:/server/bin/content/myApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/my-core.jar/com/myapp/LogManager.class
    and I can determine war name

    when class is located in jboss module it gives:
    jar:file:/C:/server/modules/system/layers/base/com/myapp/my-customization/main/my-core.jar!/com/myapp/LogManager.class
    and here I don't have info about war name
```

Finally, actual question: 
        Is there possibility that MonitoringSecond class can use LogManager.class defined in /WEB-INF/lib so that I'm not forced to move my-core.jar to jboss modules ?

If not, some other idea to determine war name from which LogManager.class has been called ?

Hope I didn't confuse it too much. 
Thanks for any answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A module in $JBOSS_HOME/modules is not possible to depend on a deployment WAR (**Dynamic** module). So It is not possible to maintain my-core.jar inside war lib folder, my-core.jar have to be located in $JBOSS_HOME/modules